# Насколько в PHP нужны структуры данных?

Tags: php, структуры-данных

Существует множество разных структур данных - *стеки, очереди, списки, деревья, map'ы* и т.д.

Но, в PHP у нас есть крутой массив. В своей практике я пока не встречал реального кода, который бы использовал в себе структуры данных.

Что это? Нежелание заморачиваться или же просто в PHP они *не нужны*?

Используете ли вы в своей работе всякого рода структуры данных?

Comment: Если вы не встречали такой необходимости — значит у вас просто нет таких нагрузок, на которых разные структуры данных становятся нужны

Comment: из области очень общего вопроса, что вы тут ожидаете услышать в качестве ответа? вэб-программирование, чаще решает весьма простые задачи, с учетом жизненного цикла http-запроса, и в основном сводятся к "получить и вывести список документов по критерию". Применение различных структур данных  не должно быть привязано к языку, оно относится к решаемой задаче. Так что в подавляющем большинстве случаев массивы и их гибкость действительно позволяют заменить все перечисленные структуры, более того, при самостоятельной реализации большинство из них все равно будет основано на использовании массивов.